# scalikejdbcでサブクエリの書き方

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

お世話になります。

scala + scalikejdbc を使っていますが、次のようなSQLをQueryDSLに直す場合の
処理がいまいちわかりません。

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.date, a.code, b.score
FROM
    source as a
LEFT JOIN
    data as b 
    ON b.code = a.code 
    AND b.date = (
        select date from data where code = a.code order by date desc limit 1
    )
```

のような書き方になった場合、最後の３行の

```
    AND b.date = (
        select date from data where code = a.code order by date desc limit 1
    )
```

部分がどのように表現したらよいかわかりません。

```
select(a.result.id, a.result.date, a.result.code, b.result.score)
    .from(source as a)
    .leftJoin(data as b).on(
         sqls.eq(b.code, a.code).and.eq(b.date, ？？？？？)
    )
```

という感じのようになるとおもうのですが、？？？？ の部分を記述しようとおもったところ
ここで分からなくなってしまっています。

初心者すぎる質問で申し訳ないのですが、どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ご存知の通り、Join句のonを指定するメソッドは2つ用意されていて、複数の条件を書く場合は、`on(onClause: SQLSyntax)`の方を使用する必要があります。

[scalikejdbc/QueryDSLFeature.scala#L412-L420](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/3.3.1/scalikejdbc-interpolation/src/main/scala/scalikejdbc/QueryDSLFeature.scala#L412-L420)

```
def on(onClause: SQLSyntax): SelectSQLBuilder[A] = {
  if (ignoreOnClause) this.copy(ignoreOnClause = false)
  else this.copy(sql = sqls"${sql} on ${onClause}", ignoreOnClause = false)
}

def on(left: SQLSyntax, right: SQLSyntax): SelectSQLBuilder[A] = {
  if (ignoreOnClause) this.copy(ignoreOnClause = false)
  else this.copy(sql = sqls"${sql} on ${left} = ${right}", ignoreOnClause = false)
}
```

`sqls.eq()`のvalueにサブクエリを渡す場合は`SQLSyntax`を渡す必要があり、QueryDSL(`SQLBuilder`)をそのままは渡せません。

[scalikejdbc/interpolation/SQLSyntax.scala#L291](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/3.3.1/scalikejdbc-core/src/main/scala/scalikejdbc/interpolation/SQLSyntax.scala#L291)

```
  def eq[A: ParameterBinderFactory](column: SQLSyntax, value: A): SQLSyntax = SQLSyntax.empty.eq(column, value)
```

[scalikejdbc/ParameterBinderFactory.scala#L99](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/3.3.1/scalikejdbc-core/src/main/scala/scalikejdbc/ParameterBinderFactory.scala#L99)

```
  implicit val sqlSyntaxParameterBinderFactory: ParameterBinderFactory[SQLSyntax] = new ParameterBinderFactory[SQLSyntax] { def apply(value: SQLSyntax) = SQLSyntaxParameterBinder(value) }
```

ただし`SQLBuilder`は`.sql`メソッドで`SQLSyntax`に変換できます。

`sqls.eq()`に書いたサブクエリ(`SQLSyntax`)は括弧で囲まれないので、`sqls.roundBracket()`を使って括弧で囲まれるようにしておくのが良いかと思います。

```scala
select(
    a.result.id,
    a.result.date,
    a.result.code,
    b.result.score
)
    .from(source as a)
    .leftJoin(data as b).on(
        sqls.eq(b.code, a.code).and
            .eq(
                 b.date,
                 sqls.roundBracket(
                     select(b.date)
                         .from(data as b)
                         .where.eq(b.code, a.code)
                         .orderBy(b.date).desc
                         .limit(1)
                         .sql
                 )
            )
    )
```

また、[SQLInterpolation](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/sql-interpolation.html)で書いてしまう方法もあります。

```scala
select(
    a.result.id,
    a.result.date,
    a.result.code,
    b.result.score
)
    .from(source as a)
    .leftJoin(data as b).on(
         sqls"""${b.code} = ${a.code} AND
               |${b.date} = (
               |  SELECT ${b.date}
               |  FROM ${data as b}
               |  WHERE ${b.code} = ${a.code}
               |  ORDER BY ${b.date} DESC
               |  LIMIT 1
               |)""".stripMargin
    )
```

Comment: harry0000さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。sqls.roundBracket()と.sqlの知識がいままでありませんでした。ご指摘の内容を参考に実装してみたところ、うまくデータが取得できました。　いままで SubQuery オブジェクトを使うのかと悩んでおりました・・・。